# How to Display a "*.png" file on a UI in QT framework?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, png

I am new to Qt Framework...

I want to display a .png pic in my Form1.ui  , 
so I dragged and dropped a Graphic view from the widget box then
I placed test.png in the same directory (inside the project folder)

and i did this in the code

```
//Form1.cpp
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"

Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->Pic1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(test.png)");

}

Form1::~Form1()
{
    delete ui;
}



//Form1.h
#ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
    class Form1;
}

class Form1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form1();

private:
    Ui::Form1 *ui;
};

#endif // FORM1_H
```

It compiled perfectly but the pic didn't appear , 
What did I Wrong ?

this is my qrc :

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Widget you should use to show pictures is a [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html). You can do it directly from QtCreator, by setting its `pixmap` property.

As others said, you should first create a resource file and then add the image to that resource file. To create a Qt Resource File, go to the menus: File > Qt > Qt Resource File.

**EDIT** To do it programatically:

```
//names starting with : means that they are on a resource file, 
//otherwise in the filesystem
QPixmap * mypix = new QPixmap(":/karim/test.png"); 
ui->your_label->setPixmap(mypix);
delete mypix;
```

Comment: Dear hexa, thank you for ur reply , can u show me how to use Qlabel and and how to set pixmap properly ? i would really appreciate it...,if u want i can post more of my code so u could know where to help... 
for the Resource File  i have created a resource file , then i opened karim.qrc , i added a prefix "/karim" and i added a test.png file,and how all of this will change this command ui->Pic1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/test.png)");??

Comment: karim, simply add to the form a QLabel, then go to its properties, scroll down, under the blueish properties, pixmap is the 3rd one. There click the `...` and select test.png from the /karim prefix.

Comment: just one last question what if i want to change them in the code ?, later on on my project the i will need to change this pic according to the user ... what do then ?

Comment: check my edit, I didn't test the code but it should be along those lines :)

Comment: The memory allocation here is unnecessary. `ui->your_label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/karim/test.png"));` works too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image to a resource file: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: Dear fredg, am using Qt Creator, i did a resource file , karim.qrc, then i added the .png file  , but still no results . is this line of code correct ?
 ui->Pic1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(test.png)");

Answer (score 0):

If you have the png in your resources, maybe change your background-image: tag:

```
ui->Pic1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/test.png)");
```

Comment: it didn't work out , please note that i didn't do anything in the main.cpp or in the headers . should i do something there ???                   for the Resource File i have created a resource file , then i opened karim.qrc , i added a prefix "/karim" and i added a test.png file,and how all of this will change this command ui->Pic1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/test.png)");??

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be :/karim/test.png ?

Comment: or possibly put in an alias in the resource file so that the image has no subpath.